# RestKit dynamic mapping with nested items

Tags: ios, dynamic, nested, mapping, restkit

I am having trouble configuring a dynamic mapping for an array of results. The result objects I'd like to map are embedded within a "container" that describes the type of the enclosed object.

I have JSON similar to the following:

```
"list": {
    "name": ""
    "item_infos": [
    {
        "type": "TaskItem",
        "item": {
            "id": 0
            "title": "A Task Item",
            "task": "..."
        }
        "url": "..."
    },
    {
        "type": "ReminderItem",
        "item": {
            "id": 0
            "title": "A Reminder Item",
            "reminder": "..."
        }
        "url": "..."
    }]
}
```

I'd like to map this as a `List` object with an array of `Item`s, where each item might be of a different type. The different `type`s are finite and known.

```
class List: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var items: NSOrderedSet
}

class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var identifier: Int32
    @NSManaged var title: String

    // Each mappable `Item` is responsible for providing its own
    // mapping object. It's overridden in the subclasses below.
    class func responseMappingForManagedObjectStore(dos: RKManagedObjectStore) -> RKEntityMapping { ... }
}

class TaskItem: Item {
    @NSManaged var task: String
}

class ReminderItem: Item {
    @NSManaged var reminder: String
}
```

How can I map the embedded `item` directly under the list using `RKDynamicMapping` while still making use of the `type` field? I'm trying something along these lines for the response mapping:

```
let listMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "List", inManagedObjectStore: store)
responseMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["name": "title"])

let dynamicItemMapping = RKDynamicMapping()
dynamicItemMapping.setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock { representation in

    let itemMapping: RKEntityMapping

    switch representation.valueForKeyPath("type") as? String {
    case .Some("TaskItem"):     itemMapping = TaskItem.responseMappingForManagedObjectStore(objectStore)
    case .Some("ReminderItem"): itemMapping = ReminderItem.responseMappingForManagedObjectStore(objectStore)
    default:                    return nil

    // This is the bit I'm failing to solve. How can I return a mapping
    // that essentially "skips" a level of the JSON, and just maps the
    // embedded `item`, not the `item_info`.
    let itemInfoMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: NSMutableDictionary.self)
    itemInfoMapping.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("item", mapping: itemMapping)
    return itemInfoMapping
}

listMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKRelationshipMapping(
    fromKeyPath: "item_infos",
    toKeyPath:   "items",
    withMapping: dynamicItemMapping))
```

With this mapping, an exception is raised:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM _isKindOfEntity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2603cb400
```

Which doesn't surprise me, as the way the dynamic mapping is set up just doesn't feel right anyway – I'm looking for a way to "skip" a level of the JSON and only map the embedded `item`.

An alternative attempt was to fully specify the `fromKeyPath` as `"item_infos.item"` for the relationship to the `listMapping`, but then I cannot use the `type` field in the dynamic mapping block to determine the type of `Item` mapping to use:

```
// ...
dynamicItemMapping.setObjectMappingForRepresentationBlock { representation in
    // `type` inaccessible from the nested item representation
    switch representation.valueForKeyPath("type") as? String {
    case .Some("TaskItem"):     return TaskItem.responseMappingForManagedObjectStore(objectStore)
    case .Some("ReminderItem"): return ReminderItem.responseMappingForManagedObjectStore(objectStore)
    default:                    return nil
}

listMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKRelationshipMapping(
    fromKeyPath: "item_infos.item",
    toKeyPath:   "items",
    withMapping: dynamicItemMapping))
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. I personally wouldn't have multiple different entities, I'd have 1 with a type identifier.

Comment: @Wain Sorry, I didn't make the problem very clear. I've updated the question, but in a nutshell the mapping examples I've given don't work – the first raises an exception, and the second tries to perform the dynamic mapping based on a key path that isn't accessible from the dictionary in the dynamic mapping block (due to the `fromKeyPath` of the relationship mapping being a level too deep). The entities are simplified for the sake of clarity/brevity in the question; in reality the objects are different enough to warrant being separate entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you're trying to do, because you're connecting a core data relationship to what will be an array of dictionaries which contains managed objects.

The simplest solution is to take your skip logic out from where it is and create all of the mappings for the managed objects (task and reminder) by adding `item.` at the start of the source key (path). So

```
"item.title" : "title"
```

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful to know I was heading down a path that wouldn't work. I suppose I was somehow hoping the dictionaries might act as an intermediate representation that would allow the items to be mapped into core data. I was also hoping to avoid having to alter the individual item mappings since they're nicely encapsulated by the object classes, and there are other routes where these mappings would be used without the `item` prefix. I suppose I'll get over it and just add a `sourceKeyPathPrefix` param to the method that returns the mapping. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The dictionary approach would only work if the list mapping had nothing to do with core data, as it is / was the relationship won't work with the intermediate because its non core-data in a core-date relationship (hope that makes sense)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for your help, I know the best way to proceed now.

Comment: Hi, @Wain! Didn't completely get it, but does it mean if I don't have CoreData in my project I can solve this problem in 'cleaner' way (comparing to prefixing all properties with middleman "item" key)? Do you know any examples for that? I have almost the same problem but would like to use existing generic mappings and reduce copypasted code. Thanks!

Comment: @slxl the answer is not specific to core data, the answer relates more to how you can mutate a source JSON structure into a somewhat different model structure

Comment: @Wain so if the answer is "I don't have an access to JSON structure" - the only way to map such structures is to use dot notation like "item.title" : "title"?

Comment: @slxl it depends on the JSON and model structures - this question is trying to combine data from 2 different containers in the JSON into a single destination model so you need to deal with that somehow